# How Can You Put Input from a User into a list?

Tags: python, list

I've been trying to make a song shuffler but i can't put input from the user into a list. I've tried to put the input into the list but it won't work. here is the code. What should i try?

```
    songs = list
    input1 = input('type in the name of a song file you have downloaded')
    songs = songs + input1
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
songs = list()
inpt = input('type in the name of a song file you have downloaded')
songs.append(inpt)
```

`list` is a function, so it needs brackets to initialise `songs` as `[]`. You append to a list by using the [`append()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) function, rather than using the addition operator. You could also use `songs = songs + [inpt]`

Answer (score 1):

You should first go through [Python basics](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) as this is typical list operation.

```py
    songs = []
    while(True):
        input1 = input('type in the name of a song file you have downloaded')
        songs = songs.append(input1)
```